# $\frac{\partial^2 a(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+ka(t,z)=g(z)\overbrace{\Rightarrow }^?a(t,z)=a(z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have a complex valued function $a(t,z)$, with $t$ and $z$ real independent variables, and I know that $a(t,z)$ satisfies the equality:

$$\frac{\partial^2 a(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+ka(t,z)=g(z)$$

where $g$ is a complex valued function of the real variable $z$ and $k$ is a constant.
Knowing these facts, can I argue (if yes, how...) that $a(t,z)$ is not a function of $t$, but only of $z$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. As a counterexample, consider a function

$$a(t,z) = h(t)f_h(z) + f_p(z)$$

where $f_h(z)$ and $f_p(z)$ are the homogeneous and particular solution, respectively, to the ODE

$$y''(z) + ky(z) = g(z)$$

Comment: Using prime for differentiation is not a very good notation with partial differentials of various kinds.

Comment: @mathreadler I very clearly stated this was an ODE, so my use of the prime notation was intentional. I must respectfully disagree with this not being good notation.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there some different kind of inference that one could do? For example, that a(t,z) must have that particular form you wrote? Or the information contained in my equality is totally ininfluent to make conclusions on a(t,z)?

Comment: You can use the commutativity of partial derivatives to show that $\partial_t a(t,z)$ must be a solution to the homogeneous equation in $z$ if you have that $a\in\mathcal{C}^3$, too. So while the solution may not be of the form I wrote, it is certainly at least of the form $a(t,z) = h_1(t)f_1(z) + h_2(t)f_2(t) + f_p(z)$ by applying existence and uniqueness of linear ODE to both the original differential equation and the $t$ derivative of it.

Comment: Can't edit my comment now but it is supposed to be $f_2(z)$. And $f_1,f_2 = \exp(\pm i \sqrt{k} z)$