# Mathematical properties of electrodynamic potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, electromagnetism

I am faced with a problem that is more mathematical than electrodynamic. However, not having a clearer or shorter title available, I preferred to highlight where the problem came from.
However, suppose we have the following function:

$$a(x,y,z)=\int _{z'=-l}^l\oint _{s'}J(s',z')\frac{e^{-jk\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}}}{4\pi \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}}ds'dz'$$

where $k$ is a real constant and $J(s',z')$ is an unknown function to be determined. The integration is made with respect to the variables $x', y', z '$, on a cylindrical surface that develops in height with the variation of $ z' $ and with cross-section (the section involves $ x '$ and $ y '$) described by a particular path determined by the curvilinear coordinate $ s' $.
Knowing that $ a (x, y, z) $, has the form written above, and knowing that it also satisfies the equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}a(x,y,z)+k^2 a(x,y,z)=f(z)$$

with $f(z)$ known function, can I argue in some way that $a(x,y,z) = a(z)$?

Bearing this in mind:

[$\frac{\partial^2 a(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+ka(t,z)=g(z)\overbrace{\Rightarrow }^?a(t,z)=a(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392032/frac-partial2-at-z-partial-z2kat-z-gz-overbrace-rightarrow-a)

surely we must take advantage of the first equation, if it introduces some useful information, but I do not understand well how to do it.

The deduction I am trying to make is made in the text of Robert S. Elliott: Antenna Theory and Design (pag. 284 and 322).
The author, using the fact that $a(x,y,z)=a(z)$, and supposing that $J(s',z')=f(s')I(z')$, writes the following equation:

$$a(z)=\left[\int_{z'=-l}^{z_0-b}+\int_{z'=z_0-b}^{z_0+b}+\int_{z'=z_0+b}^{l}\right]I(z')\oint_{s'}f(s')\frac{e^{-jkR}}{4\pi R}ds'dz'\approx$$
$$\approx \left[\int_{z'=-l}^{z_0-b}+\int_{z'=z_0+b}^{l}\right]I(z')\oint_{s'}f(s')\frac{e^{-jk|z-z'|}}{4\pi |z-z'|}ds'dz'+\int_{z'=z_0-b}^{z_0+b}I(z')\oint_{s'}\frac{f(s')}{4\pi R}ds'dz'$$

where $b$ is a small quantity and $R=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$. From this he deduces that:

$$\int_{z'=z_0-b}^{z_0+b}\oint_{s'}\frac{f(s')}{4\pi R}ds'dz' = \text{const}.$$

If one can show me how to arrive at this fundamental relation, even by other ways different than passing through the fact that $a(x,y,z) = a(z)$ I would be very grateful.
This is a fundamental relation because from it one can prove the equivalence between strip and cylindrical dipole.

Answer (score 0):

Take the equation $$ \frac{\partial^2 a(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+ka(t,z)=g(z) $$
We have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial^2 a(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+ka(t,z)\right)=\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial t}=0$$
Thus if $\varphi(t,z)=\frac{\partial a(t,z)}{\partial t}$, we have using Schwarz's theorem (assuming the functions here are $\mathcal{C}^2$)
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \varphi(t,z)}{\partial z^2}+k\varphi(t,z)=0 $$
We can easily solve it :
$$ \varphi(t,z)=A(t)e^{\sqrt{k}z}+B(t)e^{-\sqrt{k}z} $$
assuming that $\sqrt{k}=i\sqrt{-k}$ where $k<0$ (we suppose that $k\neq 0$, otherwise it is easy to solve : $$a(t,z)=\left(\iint g\right)(z)+\alpha(t)z+\beta(t)$$ with any $\alpha(t),\beta(t)$). Since $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are depending of $t$ we can't say anything, let us suppose $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ constant. Since $\varphi(t,z)=\frac{\partial a(t,z)}{\partial t}$, we can integrate this to get
$$ a(t,z)=(Ae^{\sqrt{k}z}+Be^{-\sqrt{k}z})t+h(z) $$
Putting this in the inital equation gives $\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial z^2}+kh(z)=0$ and thus $$ h(z)=Ce^{\sqrt{k}z}+De^{-\sqrt{k}z} $$
We can finally write $$a(t,z)=(At+C)e^{\sqrt{k}z}+(Bt+D)e^{-\sqrt{k}z}$$
The only way this doesn't depend of $t$ is to have $A=B=0$.

About your first equation, using what we said above, we get
$$ \varphi(x,y,z)=A(x,y)e^{\sqrt{k}z}+B(x,y)e^{-\sqrt{k}z}. $$
Notice that since you integrate $z$ from $-\ell$ to $\ell$, you have $a(x,y,-z)=a(x,y,z)$ so that $A(x,y)=B(x,y)$ and $$\varphi(x,y,z)=A(x,y)(e^{\sqrt{k}z}+e^{-\sqrt{k}z})$$
Since you integrate $(x,y)$ on a disk $A(x,y)$, only depends of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I don't think that $A(r)$ doesn't depend of $r$ (or there is a good reason in physics but it would be restrictive), thus we can't say that $a(x,y,z)=a(z)$.

Comment: Ok, I added in the question the reason why this relation is so much fundamental in antenna theory. If you see other ways to prove that fact, the problem would be definitely solved.